# How to get an xml attribute value from a table's column in a select list

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML
SET @xml = CONVERT(xml,'<data><UserType userID="123">employee</UserType></data>')  
  SELECT   (SELECT d.value('@userID', 'int')   
       FROM  @xml.nodes('//data/UserType') T(d))
```

I have a table where the column is like the XML above.  Is it possible to get the @userID value in a select statement?

In my Users table, the column 'XmlData' is of type XML.

```
SELECT
    userID -- u.XmlData

FROM Users u
```

How can I grab the userID attribute from the xml in a select statement?  I know how to parse it once, but not in a select.

Answer (score 0):

You knit those together with APPLY.  Something like:

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    SELECT T.d.value('@userID', 'int') userID 
FROM Users u
CROSS APPLY u.XmlData.nodes('/data/UserType') T(d)
```

Comment: actually XMLData is just NVARCHAR(MAX), I have to convert to xml first.

Answer (score 0):

With a little twist.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,XMLData nvarchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<data><UserType userID="123">employee</UserType></data>')

Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (convert(XML,XMLData) )) B(XData)
 Cross Apply ( Select UserID = d.value('@userID', 'int')   
                 From XData.nodes('/data/UserType') T(d)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  UserID
1   123
```

> **Update If only ONE User ID in the XML**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,XMLData nvarchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<data><UserType userID="123">employee</UserType></data>')

Select A.ID
      ,UserID = convert(XML,XMLData).value('/data[1]/UserType[1]/@userID', 'int')   
 From  @YourTable A
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea like John Cappelletti, just with CTE for conversion to XML.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, XMLData NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (XMLData)
VALUES
(N'<data><UserType userID="123">employee</UserType></data>');

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *, TRY_CAST(XMLData AS XML) AS xml_data FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , col.value('@userID','INT') AS userID
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY rs.[xml_Data].nodes('/data/UserType') AS tab(col);
```

> Output

```
+----+--------+
| ID | userID |
+----+--------+
|  1 |    123 |
+----+--------+
```